# Auto adjust box sixe to lines of text input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a box called userDescGrid, which is of a fixed size (flex: 3) and it contains the following 3 TextInputs

The second TextInput for UserDescription can vary from 1 line to 4-5 depending on how much a user describes themselves. This is fixed as it is loaded, the user cannot edit this TextInput.  However, the userDescGrid box stays a fixed height no matter what the description, so if the user enters 1 line, theres a lot of empty space below it.

How can i detect, based on the number of lines that will be presented, the right height of box to present (or have it automatically adjust the box `height` value or `flex` value)?

Remember that this will change and needs to be adaptable to different phone devices too.

```
<View style={styles.userDescGrid}>
                  <TextInput style={{color: 'green', fontWeight: 'bold'}}
                     value={this.state.UserName}
                     editable = {false}
                     multiline = {false}            
                  />
                  <TextInput style={{color: 'green', fontSize: 13,}}
                     value={this.state.UserDescription}
                     editable = {false}
                     multiline = {true}
                     maxHeight = {80}  
                  />
                  <TextInput style={{color: 'green', fontSize: 13,}}
                     value={this.state.Weblink}
                     editable = {false}
                     maxHeight = {20}    
                  />
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

 userDescGrid: {
    flex: 3,
    paddingTop: 2,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    paddingLeft: 10,
    
  },
})
```

Comment: Why you use textInput for content that is not editable ?? is not better solution just use Text and if you need style them as your inputs ? Then if you will need switch them in edit mode you will swap this component in view and display it in size depending on view side like 30% of high or something like this.

Comment: Event in browser you have to use some tricks to make textarea height auto scalable to content height. The trick is : set the Height for eg 5px and then check scrollable height and add this scrollable height to height. then in result you will get minium height witouth scrolls. But in native TextInput this won't work

Comment: I don't think you understood the requirement, or maybe i didn't explain it properly. The text is loaded on the TextInput box, its never edited. But depending on if theres 1 line or 5 lines "on the way when the component loads", i believe that i need to set a flex value that accomodates this